# sp2-0667 message file sp2 lang .msb not found and sp2-0750 error is coming on windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-xe

While i am trying to connect with with database by the command
sqlplus /nolog

than the error message is coming

"sp2-0667 message file sp2 lang .msb not found and sp2-0750 error is coming on windows"

Earlier it was working fine i think some path issue is there so can any one tell me how to resolve the issue or how to set the path on windows machine

Comment: have you checked ORACLE_HOME environment variable is set properly? I think the errors SP2-0667 and SP2-0750 are caused by ORACLE_HOME is not set correctly.

Comment: pls tell me how to set through command prompt

Comment: `C:>Set ORACLE_HOME=path to oracle home`

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `ORACLE_HOME` environment variable incorrectly may cause these errors.

On Linux, you can set ORACLE_HOME as `$ export ORACLE_HOME=path\to\oracle\home` and on Windows you can set as `C:\>set ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home/`.